# Python, Anaconda & PyCharm multiple versions of Python3

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda, versioning

I just installed Anaconda3-2019-10 on my MacBook.

I tried to make sure that my previous Python 3 version was totally uninstalled / removed from my system. Typing `python3`to the terminal didn´t work anymore.

After installing Anaconda and PyCharm (pycharm-community-anaconda-2019.3.3) I started a new Project to test everything. For that I selected to create a new Conda environment: 
[image]

After I created the process I checked the Preferences and the "Project Interpreter". This is what I found:

[image]

I expected to find two interpreters 1.) my 3.7 Python version and 2.) the Conda environment just created.

Does finding 3 versions mean that I didn´t correctly deinstall Python3 before installing anaconda or is there anything that I don´t understand here?

Do I need both versions?
If not is there a safe way to remove one of them?

For removing Python3 from my system I did almost everythin suggested in numerous posts in Stackoverflow.

Comment: Can you try creating the environment from the terminal, and then selecting it in a new PyCharm project?

Comment: Have you removed PyCharm settings? PyCharm stores settings for used interpreters.

Answer (score 0):

Upon creating a venv(virtual environment) you no longer need to worry about the existing interpreter. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html this might be of help.

Comment: I do because I want to have a clean system! :-)